# Any other performance efficient way to check if SPWeb.Exists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I want to check if a SPWeb exists in a farm. But using the below code will be very costly because every web is opened and checked. Is there any other better way to check if a web exists in a farm?

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
 {
     using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
     {
          exists = web.Exists;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you attempting to check if a site collection exists or a subsite within a site collection?

Comment: check a subsite within a site collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a full list of subsites that exist below a given web by using the Webs property of a web:

[Web.Webs property](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544824(v=office.15))

You can then check if a web in the collection has the Url that you're attempting to check without having to open each web individually like you're doing currently.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, as a workaround, you can use the following code to get all subsites from a site collection:

```
var clientContext = GetonlineContext();
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title);

        // Execute the query to the server  
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        // Loop through all the webs  
        foreach (Web subWeb in web.Webs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(subWeb.Title + "-------" + subWeb.Url);
        }
```

And then ,you can check if the specified url exists in the site collection.

More information for reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-all-subsites-from-a-site-collection-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.